How to access a variable or function in an HTML file after importing them into a main.js
I am trying to include multiple JS files into one main JS file (called main.js) and include that into my HTML file.  One of those JS files have a set of variables (called variables.js) I want to use in my HTML file.  I came across using the import/export modules so I tried to put this to use. While I was able to access the variables from variables.js within my main.js file, I am not able to access them in my HTML file.  Everytime I run the code, I keep getting the following error:
index.html:38 Uncaught ReferenceError: arrStr1 is not defined at index.html

Below is a code sample of what I am trying to do:
variables.js file
let arrStr1 = ["John", "Doe", "Jane", "Doe", "Michael", "Smith"];

export { arrStr1 };

main.js file
import { arrStr1 } from "./variables.js";

index.html
<script src = "main.js" type = "module"></script>
<script>
console.log(arrStr1);
</script>

Please help me solve this problem.  Thank you.

variables declared in a module are module-scoped, so they're accessible by standard scripts that run in the global scope. There are hacks you can do to make them global, but then you'd be misusing modules imo. Perhaps consider putting your logic in your <script> tag into your main.js module, or creating another module?

Option 1 (best practice)
You can use the <script type="module"> tag in your HTML, which will allow you to directly import the variables
Edit your HTML file as follows
<script type="module">
    import { arrStr1 } from "./variables.js";
    console.log(arrStr1);
</script>

Option 2
Make your variables or functions globally accessible to access them in your html file.
Edit your main.js as follows
import { arrStr1 } from "./variables.js";
window.arrStr1 = arrStr1;


better yet make the inline script <script type="module"> then you can import inline - and when I say "better yet", I mean that would be the correct way to use modules

"You should …" - no. One can do that, but one shouldn't. The OP should place the script code in the module.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
